# Error when splitting pyx file into pxd and pyx file

Tags: cython

I would like to split a pyx file which contains the declaration and definition of a class hierarchy into a pxd and pyx file for further  use in another cython module.

Here is my pxd file (instrument.pxd):

```
cdef struct s_detector:
    int size_x
    int size_y
    int offset
    int board_id_max
    
ctypedef s_detector Detector

cdef class Instrument:
    
    cdef int nbdet
        
    cdef Detector* detectors

cdef class D11Instrument(Instrument):
    pass
```

and here is my pyx file (instrument.pyx):

```
from libc.stdlib cimport free, malloc
    
from instrument cimport Detector, DetectorDescr, PixelInfo

cdef class Instrument:

    def __dealloc__(self):

        free(self.detectors)
        
cdef class D11Instrument(Instrument):

    def __cinit__(self):
    
        self.nbdet = 3

        self.detectors = <Detector*>malloc(self.nbdet*sizeof(Detector))
        self.detectors[0] = [256,192,0,6]
        self.detectors[1] = [32,256,49152,7]
        self.detectors[2] = [32,256,57344,8]
```

When compiling those files, I get the following kind of errors:

```
   Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
    
    cdef class Instrument:
    
        def __dealloc__(self):
    
            free(self.detectors)
                    ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    
    extensions/instrument.pyx:11:17: Cannot convert Python object to 'void *'

Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...                
            self.detectors = <Detector*>malloc(self.nbdet*sizeof(Detector))
                            ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    
    extensions/instrument.pyx:48:25: Cannot convert 'Detector *' to Python object
```

Would you know what I am doing wrong with my pxd/pyx files ?

Comment: It looks like cython doesn't find `instrument.pxd` while cythonizing the pyx-file. Maybe there is a typo in the names of files or some other problems (where are the files located, how is it cythonized)

Comment: thanks for your help It is cythonized through a setup.py file

Comment: You definitely don't need `from instrument cimport Detector, DetectorDescr, PixelInfo` - it happens implicitly.

Comment: Yeap that what I just tried, indeed it not necessary but still the errors remains

Comment: After retrying it is finally OK. Your hint works. Thanks